# If taxonomy has more than 6 posts, display show all

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy

I don't know why the SHOW ALL is not displaying. It needs to display when the there are more than 6 posts under BOOKS.

```
<?php 
for($k=0;$k<count($results);$k++){
$ID = $results[$k]['book_id'];
$args = array('p' => $ID, 'post_type' => 'attraction');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$book_img = get_the_post_thumbnail( $ID, 'medium', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
if ($book_img) {
    //NOTHING TO SHOW 
}
}
?>
<?php  
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'book',  
'showposts'=> 6,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'destinations',
        'terms'    => $current_term->term_id,
    )
)
);
$books = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<ul class="discover-books country-details">';
if ( $books->have_posts() ) {
while ( $books->have_posts() ) : $books->the_post(); 
    $book_img = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'medium', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
    echo '<li class="discover-single-box"><span class="discover-cell imageFit dimensions_img"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.$book_img.'</a><span class="bottom-content"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></span> </span></li>';
endwhile;
}
echo '</ul>';
if(count($results) > 6) {
echo '<div class="show-more"><a href="'.get_site_url().'/book?id='.base64_encode($current_term->term_id).'">SHOW ALL</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$results`? From the code listed, it doesn't seem like it's relevant to being counted.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is some code missing above, or you've only posted part.

It looks like you didn't count within your loop.  Try using:

```
$count = $books->post_count;
```

within your loop and then at the bottom just use:

```
if($count > 6) {
```

but that all needs to be within your loop (before the endwhile.)  I don't see anywhere where you reset your postdata here either, so it still MAY work, but I'd suggest changing the code a bit if this is it in entirety.

Answer (score 0):

I used found_posts instead of post_count.

THIS WORKS NOW.

```
 $count = $books->found_posts;
if($count > 6) {
echo '<div class="show-more"><a href="'.get_site_url().'/book?id='.base64_encode($current_term->term_id).'">SHOW ALL</a></div>';
}
```